How to Duplicate Slides in PowerPoint and Update Text Using VBA?
I am trying to use VBA to automate the creation of 52 slides in PowerPoint, where each slide is a duplicate of the first slide but with updated text inside a text box. The goal is to have the slides display "Week 1," "Week 2," ..., "Week 52" sequentially.
I’ve written a VBA script that successfully duplicates the slides, but the text in the text box is not being updated. The text box is not a placeholder; it’s a manually added text box on the slide.
Here’s the code I’m currently using:
Sub CreateWeeklySlides_TextBox()
    Dim ppt As Presentation
    Dim baseSlide As Slide
    Dim newSlide As Slide
    Dim shape As Shape
    Dim weekText As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ' Reference the active presentation
    Set ppt = ActivePresentation

    ' Reference the slide to duplicate (e.g., the first slide)
    Set baseSlide = ppt.Slides(1)

    ' Loop to create 51 additional slides (totaling 52)
    For i = 2 To 52
        ' Duplicate the base slide
        baseSlide.Duplicate

        ' Reference the newly created slide (it will always be the last slide)
        Set newSlide = ppt.Slides(ppt.Slides.Count)

        ' Loop through all shapes in the slide
        For Each shape In newSlide.Shapes
            ' Check if the shape is a text box
            If shape.HasTextFrame Then
                If shape.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    ' Replace the text box content with "Week X"
                    weekText = "Week " & i
                    shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = weekText

                    ' Center the text within the text box
                    shape.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter

                    ' Optionally center the text box on the slide
                    shape.Left = (ppt.PageSetup.SlideWidth - shape.Width) / 2
                    shape.Top = (ppt.PageSetup.SlideHeight - shape.Height) / 2
                End If
            End If
        Next shape
    Next i
End Sub


This is not an answer, but two possible workarounds from use of VBA. The reason is that VBA might be prohibited on some machines where the presentation is to be shown.

You might use a numbered list, which can increment across a range of slides.

Use the field for Page Numberin the text box. The page numbering can be set to start with your first item. The disadvantage is that a header or footer showing page number would be invalid.
Though I've not tried it, one could experiment to see if subtracting a number from the page number is displayed correctly. If so, then there would be no need to change the page number sequence.


